# Jest Mongo CI testing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, circleci

I'm testing some graphQL queries with jest.
I use beforeEach to clear the db (mongo)
Each test then uses graphql queries to hit some controller that reads/writes/updates something in the db.

Everything works great on my local machine and local mongo setup.

I noticed problems when testing on circleCI OR if I use some non-local db like mLab.

The tests that fail tend to look like this:
- create a new entry in the db
- return the id of that entry
- try reading or updating it using this id

the test would say something like "can't read if of null"
so it looks like even though I created an entry and got back it's id, it's still not in the database when I try to read it.

Is there any way around this?
I imagine that when I do something like

```
const todo = new Todo(props);
await todo.save();
return todo;
```

the save function doesn't actually wait for the document to be saved?

Answer (score 1):

Right so,
If anyone ever runs into something similar, the flag --runInBand is your friend. Hopefully, you won't suffer trying to find this for 7hours.
Okay, bye!